# Hibernate Attribute Converter doesn't work for setParameterList

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've a mapped Hibernate entity which one of its property is an enum that I created using the AttributeConverter interface.

It works fine for most cases, but if I use it inside a "IN" clause it doesn't work, Here is the code:

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class BankInvestmentStateConverter implements       
AttributeConverter<BankInvestmentState, Character> {

    public enum BankInvestmentState {
        ON_GOING('O'),      
        WITHDRAW('W'),
        ENDED('E'), 
        COLLECTED('C');
       ...
       .....
    }

    @Override
    public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(BankInvestmentState state) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public BankInvestmentState convertToEntityAttribute(Character dbData) {
        return ....
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_transaction_bank")
public class UserTransactionBank implements Serializable {
    ..
    ..
    @Column(name = "state")
    @Convert(converter = BankInvestmentStateConverter.class)
    private BankInvestmentState state;
    ..
    ..
}
```

Hibernate Query:

```
UserTransactionBank transaction = (UserTransactionBank)session.createQuery(
    "FROM UserTransactionBank WHERE userId=:user_id AND state IN (:statesList)")
    .setLong("user_id", user_id)
    .setParameterList("statesList", new Character[] { BankInvestmentState.ON_GOING.toChar(), BankInvestmentState.ENDED.toChar() })
    .uniqueResult();
```

Exception:

Cause:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to com.shareddata.helper.BankInvestmentStateConverter$BankInvestmentState
```

Message:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter
```

Any ideas why this happen?
by the way, if instead of using .setParameterList(...), I simply hardcoded the IN(..) it works fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this happening before the query is actually being executed, or during the mapping of the result?

Comment: It looks like hibernate ignores the Converter when using .setParameterList().

Comment: What happens if you use `String[]` instead of `Character[]` as argument to `setParameterList()`? Or maybe consider using a third argument which is a hibernate type, for example `.setParameterList("statesList", new Character[] { ... }, org.hibernate.types.StringType)`.

Comment: but the DB column in defined as 'char' and also the AttributeConverter.

Comment: Sorry I meant `org.hibernate.types.CharacterType`

Comment: If you wish to try using the converter, then try using `.setParameterList("statesList", new BankInvestmentState[] { BankInvestmentState.ON_GOING, BankInvestmentState.ENDED })`

Comment: I did that too, and it didn't convert to the Character value. it's like the AttributeConverter is ignored!